# My cin.get() is not working and hence does not stop the code

Tags: c++, exe

I'm a beginner and learing C++. When I try to run the exe file of this code it closes as soon as I press 'enter' after entering the second number. How do I pause my code to see the result?
I also tried system("pause"), it worked but I read that it only works on windows and using it is considered BAD PRACTICE, so I want to do it in a proper way. Please help

Print.h (header file I used in the main code)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
template<typename T> void print(T arg, int newline=1)
{
    if (newline)
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << arg;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../Print.h"


void calculator()
{
    print("Enter the first number: ", 0);
    int num1;
    std::cin >> num1;
    print("Choose Operation (+ - x /): ", 0);
    std::string  operation = "";
    std::cin >> operation;
    print("Enter the second number: ", 0);
    int num2;
    std::cin >> num2;
    if (operation == "+") {
        print("Output ==> ", 0);
        print(num1 + num2);
    }
    else if (operation == "-") {
        print("Output ==> ", 0);
        print(num1 - num2);
    }
    else if (operation == "x") {
        print("Output ==> ", 0);
        print(num1 * num2);
    }
    else if (operation == "/") {
        print("Output ==> ", 0);
        print(num1 / num2);
    }
    else {
        print("Error: Invalid Operation!\nPlease try again.");
        calculator();
    }

}

int main()
{
    print("Welcome!\nLets start!!");
    calculator();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `cin.get()` reads the newline left in the buffer after the number is converted.

Comment: `get` reads a character, if there is a character waiting to be read it will not stop your program. Therefore in your case there **is** a character waiting to be read. What character do you think that is?

Comment: Your call to `cin.get()` is running into the same problem that [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/) suffers from when calling `std::getline()`.

Comment: @john it's the first number I enter in the calculator. Am I right?

Comment: @Meghraj No, its the enter key that you type after the number. When you read a number it reads the digits that you type, but it does not read anything after the digits, so if you typed enter after the number, then that character is still unread. That is the character that your code reads when you call `get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way to do what you are asking for

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n'); // ignore any pending input
std::cin.get();                 // now wait for some new input
```

What beginners forget is that input can be left behind after you have read something. That left behind input is still there the next time that you read something, it doesn't go away.

You can read about the `ignore` method [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Comment: `INT_MAX` -> `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Comment: @NathanOliver I know but, `INT_MAX` is big enough for any practical purposes, and the code is hard enough to explain as it is.

Comment: the `std::cin.get()` doesn't wait before it reads the entered carriage return. You can call it twice. But with Visual Studio, it's a simple configuration option, in option / debug / uncheck  the close console at end

Comment: @dalfaB I think that should be a separate answer rather than a comment on my answer.

Comment: Chuckling, so true, command line input of more than 2 Billion characters (especially for a calculator) is a rare thing indeed (and quite impossible due to the limits imposed on command line length by the OS...)

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` is more than just a large value. It's a special case that **disables** counting of ignored characters.